# is there a clean, concise way to push/pop bash verbose and xtrace options for a funtion?

Tags: bash, function, verbose

(Linux bash 4.1.2)
I have a bash function calling another function.  The low level function wants to have -xv set for debugging, but I don't want it to mess with the values of x and v in the parent function.  I.e. I want the child function to push -xv, then restore the previous setting on return.  E.g.:

```
function outer(){ echo starting; inner; echo done; }
function inner(){
    set -xv
    echo inside
    set +xv
  }
outer
```

This works if the setting in outer is default; otherwise it forces +xv in the rest of outer's code.  I can imagine some very messy script that parses BASHOPTS, but it seems like there should be a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to share the outside code's environment or modify variables from `outside` within `inside`, you can launch a subprocess with `( inner )`

```
function outer(){ echo starting; inner; echo done; }
function inner(){
    (
        set -xv
        echo inside
    )
}
outer
```

Note that since you are executing in a subshell, you don't need to unset the x and v.

You can also simply wrap the call to inner in outer without modifying inner:

```
function outer(){ echo starting; ( inner ); echo done; }
```

You can find more information here about subshells and variable scopes.
https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html

Comment: One problem with the subshell (`(...)`) approach is for scaled scripts, because the subshell takes about 100  times longer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  local save=$-; set -x
  ...
  set +x -$save
```

Comment: This won't work if `save` contains any read-only options like `i`.

Comment: Within a shell script, "-i" has been removed from $-.

Comment: `i` is not the only problematic character.

Comment: Another minor issue is that the `set +x -$save` gets echoed, which doesn't happen with the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `local -`, which causes all options changes in the function to be local only:

```
function outer(){ echo starting; inner; echo done; }
function inner(){
    local -x
    set -x
    echo inside
  }
outer
```